# How can I count only certain items in a list?

Tags: c, list, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to allow for the user to enter a last name and delete it, if there is multiple people by the same last name, the user can then type in the first name and delete that specific individual. My issue is that I cant figure out a way to allow for the function to decipher whether or not there multiple contacts with the same last name. I can either get it to work where it only recognizes the first of the multiple contacts, or all the multiple contact, but not both scenarios. For ex. If I have a list of mike smith, ted smith, and phil stevens, I can either get it to delete one of the smiths, but not stevens, or I can get it to delete stevens but not just one of the smiths.

```
typedef struct friends_contact{

   char *First_Name;
   char *Last_Name;
   char *home;
   char *cell;
}fr;
```

Above is the structure, and below is obviously the rest of the code

```
char delete_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i)
{
    char name_search[50]={'\0'};
    char name_search3[50]={'\0'};
    char Delete[5]={'\0'};
    int flag=0;

    printf("Search by last name\n");
    scanf("%s",name_search);//Name entry

    for(i=0;i<*counter;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name_search,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)//Copys over the name entered
            flag++;
    }
    if(flag<=1)
    {
        strcpy(friends[i].Last_Name,Delete);
        printf("Name was deleted");
    }
    if(flag>1)
    {
        printf("There is more then 1 " "%s " ",please enter a first name\n",name_search);
        scanf("%s",name_search3);
        for (i=0;i<*counter;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name_search3,friends[i].First_Name)==0)
            {
                strcpy(friends[i].First_Name,Delete);
                printf("Name was deleted");
            }
        }
    }

    free(friends[i].First_Name);
    free(friends[i].Last_Name);
    free(friends[i].home);
    free(friends[i].cell);
}
```

I was trying to use a flag that counts as the first`for` loop cycles through, but all that does is count how many times it searches through the list of contacts( or the *counter).

Is there a way to get the function to count how many like last names there are so I can have the program determine when it needs to ask for the first name and when it does not?

Comment: The structure definition of `fr` would be a nice addition to this post.

Comment: I've added the structure

Comment: Why do you have if (flag<=1), should it not be if (flag==1) ? Because in your code, even if there is not a match, it would delete the counter+1th element. Is that what you want?

Comment: I've tried both examples, neither produced the results I needed, this was just the last example I had tried before i posted it on here.

Comment: @DatDudeJC, does my program not do what you wanted? I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: @anon I need the user to be able to create the list rather then the list to already be predetermined, sorry for not being clearer originally. The user inputs a list of contacts, and then when they want to delete a name, the function should determine if the last name entered has more then 1 match. If there is more then one of the same last name, then it must give the user a choice to enter the first name and delete it via that method, or if only one name matches the user delete search, then it simply just deletes that name without asking for the first name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char delete_contact(fr*friends ,int* counter, int i)
{
    char name_search[50]={'\0'};
    char name_search3[50]={'\0'};
    char Delete[5]={'\0'};
    int flag=0;

    printf("Search by last name\n");
    scanf("%s",name_search);//Name entry

    for(i=0;i<*counter;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name_search,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)//Copys over the name entered
            flag++;
    }
    if(flag == 1)
    {
        strcpy(friends[i].Last_Name,Delete);

        free(friends[i].First_Name);
        free(friends[i].Last_Name);
        free(friends[i].home);
        free(friends[i].cell);

        printf("Name was deleted");
    }
    if(flag>1)
    {
        printf("There is more then 1 " "%s " ",please enter a first name\n",name_search);
        scanf("%s",name_search3);
        for (i=0;i<*counter;i++)
        {
            if((strcmp(name_search3,friends[i].First_Name)==0) && (strcmp(name_search,friends[i].Last_Name) == 0))
            {
                strcpy(friends[i].First_Name,Delete);

                free(friends[i].First_Name);
                free(friends[i].Last_Name);
                free(friends[i].home);
                free(friends[i].cell);

                 printf("Name was deleted");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can try like this.

Comment: The program crashes as soon as you enter a name that is not a duplicate. for example 3 names, smith,smith, jones, smith works fine, but jones crashes

Comment: Yeah,you are right.It is easy to modify.I can add a variable to record the first member equal to the lastname.so that if flag == 1 or not,it will be works.
Please forgive me,my English is poor.

Comment: could you edit your post to reflect what you are saying, so I can make sure I understand what you are saying?

Comment: int search_flag = 0;
        for(i=0;i<*counter;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name_search,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)//Copys over the name entered
                flag++;
            if(flag == 1)
                search_flag = i;
        }
        if(flag == 1)
        {
             strcpy(friends[search_flag].Last_Name,Delete);

              free(friends[search_flag].First_Name);
              free(friends[search_flag].Last_Name);
              free(friends[search_flag].home);
              free(friends[search_flag].cell);

        printf("Name was deleted");
        }
  Understand?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of simply counting the number of matches, the best thing to do here is to have a second list, where you add the indices that match. This way, when the parsing is over, if this new list has just a single element, delete it - else, you have the indices of the original list and can even present all the matching entries to the user.

There is an error in your logic as well in that you don't record the index of the last matching name (even on the case of there being just one) - you always delete the emeent of index "i" after using i to count from 0 to "counter", if there is a single match.

Answer (score 0):

Check for memory leaks yourself . I won't spoon feed you. :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct friends_contact{

   char *First_Name;
   char *Last_Name;
   char *home;
   char *cell;
}fr;

void delete_contact(fr *friends ,int counter)
{
    char name_search[50]={'\0'};
    char name_search3[50]={'\0'};

    int flag=0;
    int i;

    printf("Search by last name\n");
    scanf("%s",name_search);//Name entry

    for(i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
        if(strcmp(name_search,friends[i].Last_Name)==0)//Copys over the name entered
            flag++;
    }
    if(flag==1)
    {

       friends[i].Last_Name = NULL;
        printf("Name was deleted");
    }
    if(flag>1)
    {
        printf("There is more then 1 " "%s " ",please enter a first name\n",name_search);
        scanf("%s",name_search3);
        for (i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            if(strcmp(name_search3,friends[i].First_Name)==0)
            {
                friends[i].Last_Name = NULL;
                printf("Name was deleted");
            }
        }
    }


}


int main()
{
    fr arr[3];

    arr[0].First_Name = "john";
    arr[1].First_Name = "jack";
    arr[2].First_Name = "jake";


    arr[0].Last_Name = "smith";
    arr[1].Last_Name = "smith";
    arr[2].Last_Name = "fox";

    delete_contact(arr,3);

    return 0;
}
```